# Parsing Strings with Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, parsing, dictionary

I could use some tips on how to go about extracting only the relevant info from a string.

This is my string:

```
{"[0000,0000]":["TEST1"],"[7418,7418]":["TEST1"],"[5817,6000]":["TEST1"],[\"8726\",\"8726\"]":["TEST1"],"[0,9999]":["TEST1"]}
```

From this I would like a list that looks like this:

```
0000-0000
7418-7418
5817-6000
8726-8726
0-9999
```

I've been reading around and I saw that the String split/concat api might be the best way to go. But that too is not quite working for me. Is there some feature that I can leverage?

Comment: thats a dictionary... not a string?

Comment: `is not quite working for me` Not working _how_? What exactly have you tried and _how_ did it fail to produce the expected results?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "unclear what you're asking" because it's talking about splitting and concatenating strings but showing some kind of unknown processing to the string keys of a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string appears to be a representation of a dictionary; you can actually get a dictionary object by doing

```
d = json.loads(your_string)
```

and then just use `d.keys()` to extract the info you're looking for, if I'm reading it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
print "\n".join(s.strip("[]").replace(",","-") for s in d)
```

maybe I guess